# Cast String cannot to org.apache.cassandra.dht.Token in Cassandra

Tags: jsp, struts2, cassandra, token

I'm writing a Cassandra cluster monitoring tool. So first of all I try to get tokens of all members in the cluster, but problems came..

Some related codes are as follows:

```
RingNode ring = clusterManager.listRing();
Map<Token, String> rangeMap = ring.getRangeMap();
List<Token> t = ring.getRanges();
for (Token token : t) {
     ...
}
```

In the function `listRing()`, a `List<Token>` is defined like this:

```
List<Token> ranges = new ArrayList<Token>(r.getRangeMap().keySet());
```

But when a breakpoint occurred, the list of `Token` seems to become a list of `String` so when it comes to the `for` part, there is error reported:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.cassandra.dht.Token
Actions.NodeStatus.execute(NodeStatus.java:57)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:432)
```

I don't know where went wrong. My Cassandra version is 1.0.7 (the same problem occurred when using 0.8.5..). Or the problem is about JSP or struts2?

Answer (score 0):

1) Try Cassandra 1.2.6 (latest)

2) It is not clear from your code where breakpoint occurs. Put more details

Comment: I want to try cassandra 1.2.6 but our system is based on 1.0.7 thus there might be some compatible problems?

Comment: The breakpoint occurs right in the `for(Token token : t)`. I don't really know why there is the `ClassCastException` since I never cast..